# php save data into database within an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, arraylist

In php I have a form like this

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table id="user-data">
        <tr>
            <td>Firstname</td>
            <td>Lastname</td>
            <td>Age</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstname[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lastname[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="age[]"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstname[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lastname[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="age[]"></td>
        </tr>       
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Now I want to insert the data into mysql table. For that my script is like this so far now

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$uname = 'root';
$pwd  = 'root';
$db = 'Test';
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pwd,$db);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
echo '<pre>';
print_r($firstname);
print_r($lastname);
print_r($age);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Now from here I want to know how to insert the values into database within the array. Any help and suggestions will be really apprecaible. Thanks

Comment: If you're not using a framework PDO should be a good choice http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: You can find your answer [here](http://evolt.org/node/60222/) quite nicely explained :)

Answer (score 0):

Use insert statement, you can see how to do that here :

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: within array how to insert the data into database that I want to know.

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert all the firstnames, lastnames and ages into the database? Use foreach on the $firstname variable and go from there.

EDIT:

```
$numberInArray = count($firstname);
for ($i=0; $i<$numberInArray; $i++) {
   // query with $firstname[$i], $lastname[$i] and $age[$i]
}
```

This way you will first count the number of variables in the array, and then you will walk through all of the arrays, and insert these values. I hope you can write the INSERT query yourself, using your framework (I would suggest using prepared queries with pdo for example).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$firstNameVal = $lastNameVal = $ageVal ='';
foreach ($firstname as $fn) {
    $firstNameVal .= $fn;
}
foreach ($lastname as $ln) {
    $lastNameVal .= $ln;
}
foreach ($age as $ag) {
    $ageVal .= $ag;
}
"insert into tablename (firstname,lastname,age) values ($firstNameVal,$lastNameVal,$ageVal)";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
        for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['firstname']);$i++) {
            $firstName = $_POST['firstname'][$i];
            $lastName = $_POST['lastname'][$i];
            $age = $_POST['age'][$i];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (firstname,lastname,age) values ('".$firstName."','".$lastName."','".$age."')";
        }
    }
```